# How to publish python unittest results to azure pipeline

Tags: azure, flask, yaml, azure-pipelines, python-unittest

I am trying to build a pipeline azure DevOps. I build a basic Flask website and wrote a Unittest script for it. It basically all works perfect. When i commit to azure repos the pipeline will do his thing and the test will run. The thing i want is to see the test results, i see all these tutorials for Pytest but not for Unittest.

```
trigger:
- Development

jobs:
- job: 'Test'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest' # other options: 'macOS-latest', 'windows-latest'
  strategy:
    matrix:
      Python37:
        python.version: '3.7'

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '$(python.version)'

  - script: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      python -m pip install -e .
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'
  
  - script: |
      python -m unittest discover -p "*.py" > results.txt
    displayName: unittesting
```

This is my Yaml file that runs the pipeline.

This is how my results look when running the pipeline.
[Pipeline results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9fet.png)

Is there a way to publish these results with Unittest and have them in azure pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

If your unit tests are written using unittest module, dont worry

**pytest can run unittest as well !!!**

Add below yaml code snippet to your azure pipeline.

1. Run your unittest with pytest
2. Generate Junit XML output
3. Publish the output back to azure pipeline

```
- script: |
    cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
    python -m pytest $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/<unit_tests_path>/*.py --junitxml=test-unit.xml
  displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: 'test-unit.xml'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to make your test script generate results in a format that DevOps can understand, i.e. JUnit XML.
There's an [example in MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops#test-with-pytest-and-collect-coverage-metrics-with-pytest-cov) (which includes coverage as well):

```yaml
- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pip install pytest-cov
    pytest --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --cov=. --cov-report=xml
  displayName: 'pytest'
```

Alternatively, using [unittest-xml-reporting](https://pypi.org/project/unittest-xml-reporting/) should give you results in JUnit XML format as well.

Once you have that, then you can use [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml) to upload results and make them visible in DevOps UI, i.e.:

```yaml
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/test-*.xml'
```